# Format specifier in C: can %s can store integer values?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

Can %s format specifier that stores string consisting of sequence character store sequence of integers? If yes..can you please explain?

Comment: No it can't. Specifiers must match the type of the output variable they write into. Otherwise your program has undefined behavior. Nothing more to it, the end.

Comment: `%s` can't store anything, neither `char[]` nor `int[]`

Comment: `%s %d %e %f % g` are the format specifier.. they doesn't stores value

Comment: In C `char`'s can be taken as integers. A `char`s bit-width depends on the C implementation in use. It typically is 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers are represented with characters anyway, so YES you can read a number with the `"%s"` specifier and store it in a `char[]` array, after that you can change the representation of the character string to a numeric variable (*a binary representation*) with the use of `atoi()` or `strtol()`.